# Como descobrir se um nome de arquivo é válido?

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo, sistema-de-arquivos

Isso talvez não seria um grande problema se você sabe que a aplicação vai rodar no Windows por exemplo. Mas como pode rodar em plataformas diferente isso muda. Tem que pesquisar e verificar se tem algo inválido na *string* para cada plataforma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O .NET possui métodos prontos para pegar quais são os caracteres inválidos da plataforma. Se for o nome completo pode usar o método [`GetInvalidPathChars()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0#System_IO_Path_GetInvalidPathChars), e só para o nome do arquivo sem caminho é o [`GetInvalidFileNameChars()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0#System_IO_Path_GetInvalidFileNameChars). Mas não é garantido que sempre tenha a informação correta, porque a informação não vem da plataforma, e olhando o código fonte percebe-se que eles não servem para muita coisa, não me pergunte porquê existem.

Além disso não tem como verificar se um nome é válido para outra plataforma que não a de execução atual, o que te obrigaria fazer seu próprio método com uma listagem de todos os caracteres que você sabe que são inválidos segundo a documentação da plataforma (Ex.: [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)). Então essa deve ser a solução real.

Depois disso precisa usar RegEx ou fazer um laço ou usar LINQ para ver se há algum desses caracteres no nome do arquivo que deseja analisar. Se quiser uma facilidade teria que criar um método *sanitizador*, não tem pronto.

Comment: Quem negativou poderia dar uma resposta mostrando seu conhecimento sobre o assunto e dizendo o que é o certo para ajudar a todos.